# Testing redux-observable Epic with debounce operator

Tags: reactjs, epic, redux-observable

Having the following redux-observable epic:

```js
export const mouseEventEpic = (action$, store) =>
 action$
  ::filter(action => action.type === MOUSE_OUT || action.type === MOUSE_OVER)
  ::debounceTime(200)
  ::map(action => getMappedAction(action, store));

const getMappedAction = (action, store) => {
 switch (action.type) {
      case MOUSE_OVER:
        return {type: "OVER"};
      case MOUSE_OUT:
        return {type: "OUT"};
 }
};
```

and the following test

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { mouseEventEpic } from '...';
    
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(mouseEventEpic );
const mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleware]);

describe('Epic...', () => {
 let store;

 beforeEach(() => {
  store = mockStore({});
 });

 it('test...', () => {    
  store.dispatch({type:'MOUSE_OVER'});    
  expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal([]);
 });
});
```

The store.getActions() returns an array with one action - "MOUSE_OVER". Whereas when removing the debounce it returns another (and the expected) action - "OVER".
I'd like to stub/remove the debounce operator in the test.
Tried to follow the ideas in [this link](https://blog.hyphe.me/rxjs-testing-in-real-world-applications/) using the sinon stub function with no success.
Some guideline on how to mock a RxJS operator or specifically the debounce/throttle would be appreciated.
Using React, Mocha, Chai, Enzyme...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, one would be to stub it out, but it has to be stubbed out *before* your epic is started, otherwise the operator has already been called and stubbing it will do nothing (this may be what happened when you tried).

I believe you'd need to move your middleware/store creation logic into the `beforeEach`, and stub out `debounceTime` in there too, *before* you create the middleware/store.

As far as how to stub, one example using sinon is:

```
// inside `beforeEach()`
const debounceTime = sinon.stub(
  Observable.prototype, 'debounceTime',
  function () {
    // returning the upstream Observable which
    // means debounceTime is now effectively a
    // a pass through (does nothing)
    return this;
  }
);

// example inside a test
assert(debounceTime.withArgs(200).calledOnce);

// later, probably in `afterEach()`
debounceTime.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

My second try. Looks like the stub never called probably still called (if at all) sometime later. Again, if removing the ::debounceTime(200) line, everything works just fine.

```
let sandbox, debounceTime, epicMiddleware, mockStore, store;

beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    debounceTime = sandbox.stub(
        Observable.prototype, 'debounceTime',
        () => {             
            console.log('-----------------inside debounce stub') //never called...
            return this;
        }
    );

    epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(combineEpics(stackedOverTimeMouseEventEpic));
    mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleware]);
    store = mockStore({});
});

afterEach(() => {
    epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(stackedOverTimeMouseEventEpic);
    debounceTime.restore();
    sandbox.restore();
});

it('Epic...', () => {
    const ret = store.dispatch({"type": "MOUSE_OVER"});     
    // expect(debounceTime.withArgs(200).calledOnce).to.be.true;    //returns false
    expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal([]);                   //returns [{"type": "MOUSE_OVER"},{"type": "@@redux-observable/EPIC_END"}]
});
```